# What's the best seed number for generating random numbers in java?

Tags: java, random, dynamically-generated, random-seed

I need to generate quite random numbers in java, but don't want repetitive results each time my method calls. Consider this code:

```
Random rand = new Random(seed);
if (rand.nextBoolean())
     // do something...
```

so what's the best seed to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try with `System.currentTimeMillis()`,

- is changing with the time so you are not hardcoding constants anywhere..
- you dont need any external lib dependency
- is statically called, so no need to create an object

Comment: But it's not random. It may be fine for some use cases, but certainly not all. Especially DO NOT use this for anything even closely resembling cryptographic purposes (e.g. encrypting stuff, generating passwords, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't the `Random` empty constructor use the current ticks as default seed? At least that's what C# does. If so, the empty constructor is as good as any. Documentation for Java only says "This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor."

**Edit**: So here is what I found:

```
public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }
private static volatile long seedUniquifier = 8682522807148012L;
```

You cannot guarantee randomness though. It's pseudo-random and someone can potentially figure out future values based on previous ones. If security isn't a major concern, you can just use `new Random()`. Unless you use it improperly, like initializing it inside a loop, it should do just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
if (rand.nextBoolean())
 // do something...
```

Comment: But it's not random. It may be fine for some use cases, but certainly not all. Especially DO NOT use this for anything even closely resembling cryptographic purposes (e.g. encrypting stuff, generating passwords, etc.)